# Fill remaining text box slots with X's in Access form?

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on updating a form to enter Batch numbers for products. To scan the barcodes we use 13 characters. The batch numbers are not that long so I want a way to fill the remaining 5-7 spots with a variable, "X" for example. Is this possible with Access or should I just set a rule to make sure 13 characters are entered. I could try an input mask but I feel because the batch numbers are unique and vary, I could use 6 or 8 numbers at any given time. Thanks!

Comment: "I could use 6 or 8 numbers at any given time" - is it 13 characters, or 6, or 8?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean the Batch number is 6-8 numbers. Total needed is 13.

Comment: Think about the question as if you were explaining it to your grandmother, then add the details you'd tell her into your question by clicking the "edit" link below the text of your question.  Also, you may want to look at the [tour](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: New here, sorry. Can I get it moved there or do I just re-post it?

Comment: I would think about adding some detail to your question; if you post it like this on StackOverflow, it'll probably get closed very quickly.

Comment: Let me see if I understand correctly: When you read a barcode you can get something like `12345678` and you would like to store somethink like `12345678XXXXX` (or some other character). Is that what you want?